# Android Facebook SDK keystore not asking or password

Tags: android, facebook

I'm trying to use the Facebook SDK for Android mobile applications.

I've in this site: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/ that I should get the keystore from my Android SDK.

I'm doing as follows in the Windows command prompt, where I'm referring to the exact place of the keystore and the [OpenSSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSSL) files:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

I get a hash key, but I'm not prompted for entering a password...

In the site, it says that if I'm not asked to enter a password ("android") then I didn't write the path right, although I did!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to check the path again.
I generated the key with the correct path. It was prompted for a password. As a result, I got the key.
Then I generated the key with the wrong path. I got different key.
You can see it in the screenshot.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that if your path is wrong:

It will not ask you to enter the password. However, if your path is the right one then it will ask you to enter your password which is "android" so the first key is the right one.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the path of debug.keystore is correct i found this file in

```
C:\Users\Myname\ .android\debug.keystore
```

once done this make sure to correct path to ssl here is mine:

```
C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl
```

once done both use this comment in your jdk or jre folder in java where key tool file exists

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\ali Roshan\.android\debug.keystore" | "C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" sha1 -binary |"C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" base64
```