# Error: Invalide android:_key parameter. The key does not match allowed key

Tags: android, facebook

Hy! I tried to integrate the facebook sdk with my android app. I obtain my key kashes using this comand:

> keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator.android\debug.keystore" | "C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" sha1 -binary |"C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" base64

After that I, i create a new facebook application, where i selected native android app and i give my hashkey. 
[image]

But when I run the app, I receive this error: 
[image]

Can someone to help me?

Comment: did you check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16767672/key-hash-doesnt-match-while-facebook-login-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this when session open

```
try {
            PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
            for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
                }
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

        }
```