# toByteArray() won't be resolved for facebook login

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I am building an app which requires facebook login and authentication.

I am following

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started#create-app

I got this error: when I hit the facebook login button:

[image]

Multiple posts say that this code should resolve the error

[Key hash doesn't match while facebook login in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16767672/key-hash-doesnt-match-while-facebook-login-in-android)

:

```
  try {
            PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                    "com.hitup.hitup",
                    PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
            for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
            }
        }
        catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

        }

        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e)
        {

        }
```

however the toByteArray() method cannot be resolved!

[image]

How can I resolve this error and achieve the simple facebook login for my app?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You must import a [`android.content.pm.Signature`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/Signature.html) and not a [`java.security.Signature`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/Signature.html).

Answer (score 6):

```
from Logcat you can get hash key of facebook please do copy from logcat which having Logcat tag "KeyHash" and put it in your project on developer.facebook site
```

[image]

```
import android.content.pm.Signature;

      try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                **"do not forgot to your package name"**, PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.d("KeyHash:",
                    Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
        }
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

    }



OR 

1. for Android default keystore  : add this to in your terminal 
 
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64

2. for signed keystore 

keytool -exportcert -alias aliasname -keystore keystorename | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

Comment: How can that be implemented?

Comment: you have implement it already see  Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT)); so, you can see your logcat which having tag "KeyHash" copy its value

Comment: Okay I think I understand...but problem is that                 Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
didn't produce anything

Comment: It didn't print I added my packagename I am not sure why it is not :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61818/discussion-between-vaishali-and-jabari-johnson).