# Facebook share dialog android return error

Tags: android, facebook, key, share

I want to [share](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share#linkshare) a simple link from my android app.

I followed the *getting started* [guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/) from Facebook and all seem okay in my app since I can open the share dialog.

- I imported FacebookSDK project and linked library
- I set my appproperly (package/class name and dev hash keys)
- My manifest has right permissions and meta-data

Additional infos :

- I use a real device for debug
- I run a test app as admin
- I'm running a simple share code sample from an activity

I had troubles to generate hash keys but that [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6665263/2735839) helped me. I got an error saying XXX key (different from the one I generated) doesn't match.

Then I tried the method explained [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/#samples) (at the end) to log another key.

Since now, I just get a toast saying "*Something went wrong. Please try again*."

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved my problem thanks to another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16768681/2735839). The problem is I was trying to generate a key outside my main (first) class.