# Facebook hash key for Generate signed apk

Tags: android, facebook, hash

I working on App with a facebook login feature, its just a test.
I have a problem,with my Android Key Hash.
When i generate signed Apk.
I did what are recommend on facebook developer,and it's still not working.
I get Error message

"Invalid key hash. The key hash xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx= does not match any stored key hashes.Configure your app key hashes at https://developers.facebook.com/908744315875240"

But if i am using ADB the app is working great. 
I followed this link :[Key hash for Android-Facebook app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388992/key-hash-for-android-facebook-app)
and this one here [Key hash doesn't match while facebook login in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16767672/key-hash-doesnt-match-while-facebook-login-in-android)
to get my hash key. 
I also updated my Sample App Settings to this hash key,and on my facebook App 
please help thx :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate hash key for your keystore which you use to sign the app. Add both hash keys (debug keystore and your keystore which you use to sign the app) in app setting page of the Facebook.

Comment: Please refer to this link  and check 'Setting a Release Key Hash' https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started

Comment: i did it doesn't work.
i did a new one alias name AI and easy password

Comment: @zion did you find the solution ? i have the same problem.