# Facebook(APP_ID) in android

Tags: android, facebook

I'm using Facebook SDK in android , to share in user wall , but

```
Facebook fb=new Facebook(APP_ID);
```

this line of code  is deprecated and application doesnt work.. (is there any update in FB SDK ? )

Comment: Facebook sdk 3.0 is the latest https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/

Comment: which one SDK version you are using

Comment: I'm using SDK3 ,but i followed an old tutorial

Comment: I think this should not be a problem, i was also messing up with this same thing but got my code working after getting proper key hash for the released mode and debugger mode. Try this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10042022/how-to-create-a-facebook-key-hash) for getting your key-hash for the application and be sure that you are using the correct app-id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you sign your Android app using a proper key (not the default debug Android key) and your App is not in Sandbox mode. 
A lot of help is available on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/

Hope it helps.