# facebook key hash for android when having same projects in different system

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook, hash

We are having this problem from weeks,I did the whole keyhash thing correctly and got the key hash too from this code:

```
enter code here try {
    PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
            "Your package name", 
            PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
    for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
        md.update(signature.toByteArray());
        Log.d("Your Tag", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
        }
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

}

}
```

but when i try to  copy the project in my friend's eclipse to work together on a same project and using same facebook app
it shows 
invalid key hash.the key w7*********** does not match any store key hash 
so what's the problem and how can i resolved this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Here is the trick you need to copy the hash that you get w7***********. 
Then you need to open your facebook app at developers.facebook.com.

1- Open you app at developers.facebook.com.

2- go to the Settings

3- paste that key hash that you copied to key hash box and then hit save changes.

Now run your app it will work.

Answer (score 0):

**Generate key hase for your friends pc also.**

You need to generate keyhash from your pc and add it to developers facebook where you have created your facebook app. So one is your friends pc key hash and one is of your pc's keyhash.so you will get working with facebook from both system.

So you have `Multiple` key hashes added on facebook project one is of your system and second is of your friends pc.

follow this link [How to create a Facebook key hash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10042022/how-to-create-a-facebook-key-hash) to create new facebook keyhash from your pc.